# Internationalizing a duration via gwt Messages

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, duration

I want to include a timeout duration, like "25 seconds" or "1 minute", in a user-facing message. Is there a way to do this in gwt?

From [this resource](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n.html), I know that I can do dates like this:

```
@DefaultMessage("Last update: {0,date,medium} {0,time,medium}")
String lastUpdate(Date timestamp);
```

but there doesn't seem to be anything like:

```
// hypothetical
@DefaultMessage("Requests time out after {0,duration}")
String timeout(Interval duration); // also Interval is a JodaTime concept...
```

Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JodaTime still isn't really available for GWT (there are/were [several projects](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/lBpcCfNm2d4/qctwPFWYjLgJ), but unfortunately none ever really established itself). I hope someday we'll see JavaSE 8's new Date API in GWT!

Until then, I would use the following approach:

- Storing the duration as a number of seconds (or milliseconds if required).
- Creating one internationalized message for 0-59 seconds, one for 1-59 minutes, and one for 1-... hours.
- Each of these messages can use [Plural Forms](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nMessages.html#PluralForms).
- Selecting the best message (seconds/minutes/hours) programmatically.